# Parsing package error in android when install 2.3.4 android device

Tags: android

When i install the apk in android 2.3.4 device it shows "Error on package parsing"application developed on android 2.2 version.How can i install this app into 2.3.4 device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the android target in your project (Properties -> Android -> Change the version). Rebuild the project and export the .apk file.Try to install the .apk in devide again.

Answer (score 0):

You just removed the below line from your manifest file.
    `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=" " />`